# cyclic bayesian network

Tags: math, bayesian, bayesian-networks

i have several elements A,B,C,AB,ABC,.. (see image below) where each element either exists or not. the rule that governs this system is as follows: if AB exists, then A and B must also exist. generally speaking if a tupel exists, all smaller tupels which are subsets of this tupel must also exist. furthermore if a tupel does not exist, all tupels which make up a superset of this tupel do not exist.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fNl6.gif

Example:
Given ABC exists then A, B, C, AB, AC, BC exist too. Given BC does not exist then ABC,BCD,ABCD do not exist either.

now what i struggle with is, how do i calculate e.g. P(AB|A,B,!ABC) which means the probability that AB exists, given A exists, B exists and ABC does not exist. foreach element i have a basic starting probability p(X) which tells me how likely it is for X to exists given NO constraints. and usually i check the existence of A,B,C,D,ABCD beforehand so the system has boundaries.

my problem is that this is a cyclic network. i would be very grateful for any help as i tried solving this problem for the last couple of weeks without success. i only want to calculate the probability that one element exists, given any situation/constraint. note that elements like AB and !BD are not independent.

Comment: Are you assuming that the probability that each base element (e.g.: A, B) exists is independent of each other? I.e.: P(AB|A,B) = P(A)*P(B)?

Comment: The order in which you check whether elements exist is vitally important.

Comment: yes i assume that A and B are independent. elements that dont include each others letters are independent of each other.
the order in which i check the elements, is the problem i want to calculate. i want to check elements with a high information gain first, which is the probability that it works or not multiplied with the number of elements i can skip when it works or not.

Comment: i am sorry, A and B are independend. but the forumla P(AB|A,B) = P(A)*P(B) is not true, since AB does not have to exist when A and B exist seperately.

Comment: @makro: If A and B are independent but P(AB|A,B) is not equal to P(A)*P(B), then I'm afraid I misunderstand your description. What does P(AB|A,B) equal then?

Comment: because of independence it would initially be: P(A,B)=P(A)*P(B). note its A,B not AB.
to determine AB for a general situation X it would be: P(AB|X)=P(AB|A,B)*P(A|X)*P(B|X). and i think P(AB|A,B) cannot be resolved any more, it is a value that has to be estimated.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use bayesian network, then first you need to add directions in your chart, which would be from bottoms up.

Then draw the DAG with your p values using MSBNx, which you can get from: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/adapt/msbnx/ and run Bayesian inference, you should have no problem doing Probability queries on it.